# Automatically Add New Rows to Sheet (Sheet 1) When Updated Imported Sheet (Sheet 2) Contains New Data

Tags: excel, vba

I am not very experienced with Excel Macros/VBA. However, I would like to add code that adds a new row (after the filled cells) to Sheet 1 when a new column 1 value is present on Sheet 2 (The imported Sheet), but the column 1 value is not yet present on Sheet 1 from the previously imported sheet. I would like the new row that has been added to sheet 1 to also include the column 1 value from the imported sheet.

Please let me know if any clarification is needed.

I have looked at other similar questions but running the modules always end up with an error

Comment: Would be useful to add some context around what it is you're actually doing.  What for example is the "imported sheet" - where is that coming from and what is its purpose?

Comment: The imported sheet is a report of active listings I have on my website with column 1 including the website item number. I want to ensure that I am tracking all active listings on sheet 2 with manually entered data not present on the imported sheet

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AddNew()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim dict As Object, k, n As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long
   
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws1 = .Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws2 = .Sheets("Sheet2")
    End With
    
    ' existing values
    With ws1
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 1 To lastrow
           k = Trim(.Cells(r, 1))
           If Len(k) > 0 Then dict(k) = r
        Next
    End With
    
   ' imported
    With ws2
        For r = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
           k = Trim(.Cells(r, 1))
           If Not dict.exists(k) Then
               lastrow = lastrow + 1
               ' add row
               ws1.Cells(lastrow, 1) = k
               dict(k) = r
               n = n + 1
           End If
        Next
    End With
       
    MsgBox n & " rows added to " & ws1.Name, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you change the above code to add the new row after the last row that contains information in column b rather than column a. Some of my rows on sheet 1 do not have content in column a

Comment: @TaylorWiseman OK done

Comment: What would need to be changed if my imported sheet was "sheet 6" and the other sheet is "sheet 2"?

Comment: @Taylor `Sheets("Sheet1")` to `Sheets("Sheet2")` and `Sheets("Sheet2")` to `Sheets("Sheet6")`

Comment: Maybe change at least one of those sheet names to (eg) "Tracking" to make your life easier...

Comment: Or change sheet 2 to sheet 6 before you change sheet 1 to sheet 2 :P